# Composer Drush installation issue

Tags: 8, drush

I'm setting up multiple drush folders to run for older versions of Drupal. I run composer require "drush/drush:dev-master" and I get this error:

> [InvalidArgumentException]
>   Package drush/drush at version dev-master has a PHP requirement
>   incompatible with your PHP version (5.5.38)

at command line, php -v yields: 7.1.0

How do I find and fix this issue?

Comment: It seems Composer is configured to use a specific PHP version. You need to tell use a bit more about your environment - OS, how you installed PHP and so on.

Comment: Thanks Mac OSX El Capitan, installed drush 7 for legacy projects, drush 8 install is giving me issues. Running under Mamp Pro 4.5.

Comment: So PHP 5.5.38 is the default PHP coming with your Mac. You have then installed PHP 7.1.0 (as part of Mamp Pro) and in the terminal/command line you are successfully using that version. From the same terminal Composer is reporting the old PHP version? That doesn't make much sense. Maybe show us the exact commands you are running in the terminal? And also add the output from `which php`, `which composer`, `echo $PATH` (as part of the terminal session). You can paste the terminal text as code in your question.

Comment: @hansfn `which php` returns /usr/bin/php,  `which composer` returns /usr/bin/composer,  `echo $PATH` returns /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5, which shows why i'm getting that error.